# How do I package an electron app when using express as the feed?

Tags: node.js, express, electron

I'm trying to build an electron application using electron-packager, and whilst it succeeds in building, when I try and open it I get an error that it can't access my index.ejs file.

I haven't tried anything to fix it but I suspect that it could be fixed by not using express, however that is not an option because I need express for an API that the electron app requires.

My Index.js

```js
const express = require('express');
const exp = new express();

// Electron 
const {app, BrowserWindow} = require('electron');

// Making the window 
function appReady() {
    mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
        width: 550,
        height: 350,
        autoHideMenuBar: true,
        useContentSize: true,
        resizable: false
    });
    mainWindow.loadURL('http://localhost/');
    mainWindow.focus();
}

// Actually starting the app 
app.on('ready', appReady);

// Express 
const AEStxt = require('./AES.json')

exp.set('json spaces', 2);

exp.get('/api', function (req, res) {
    res.json({
        MainAES: AEStxt.MainAES
    });
});

// Pretty page 
exp.engine('html', require('ejs').renderFile);

exp.use(express.static(__dirname));

exp.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.render('./index.ejs', {mainaes: AEStxt.MainAES, aes1003: AEStxt.Pak1003});
});

exp.listen(process.env.PORT || '80', () => {
    console.log('Listening on 80');
});
```

My views/index.ejs file

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            #pakmaintext {
                margin-top: 20px;
                color: white;
                font-family: Burbank;
                font-size: 18px
            }

            #pak1003text {
                margin-top: 30px;
                color: white;
                font-family: Burbank;
                font-size: 18px
            }

            body {
                background: url(gradient.jpg);
                background-size: 100%;
            }

            @font-face {
                font-family: 'Burbank';
                src: url(fonts/Burbank.ttf);
            }

            button {
                margin-top: 20px;
            }
        </style>
        <script>
            function myFunction() {
                var x = document.getElementById("mainpakdiv");
                if (x.style.display === "none") {
                    x.style.display = "block";
                } else {
                    x.style.display = "none";
                }
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <center>
                <button onclick="myFunction()">v10.10 Main AES</button>

                <div id="mainpakdiv">
                    <p id='pakmaintext'><%= mainaes %></p>
                </div>

                <div id="aes1003div">
                    <p id="pak1003text"><%= aes1003 %></p>
                </div>
        </center> 
    </body>
</html>
```

What is expected is that when I build and open the electron app, it loads my pretty page, but what I get is `Error: Failed to lookup view "./index.ejs" in views directory "C:\Users\path to project dir\views"`

Thanks, Sam.

Answer (score 0):

EJS has a more natural integration with Express than what you are doing:

1. Install EJS (`npm i ejs`)
2. Configure the view engine in Express (`exp.set('view engine', 'ejs');`)
3. Render an EJS view (`res.render('index', { ... })`), notice no need for relative paths or explicit extensions.

Comment: I don't think you understand, I am using EJS with express, and my electron app is just loading that express page.

Comment: @SamHep0803 ah no problem, if it's an embedded within an Electron app then the `static` part shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: do you have discord @James ?

Comment: @SamHep0803 no sorry

Comment: Ok, well I tried what you said and I am now getting `Error: No default engine was specified and no extension was provided.`

Comment: @SamHep0803 that's odd because step 2 in my answer _is_ setting the default view engine therefore as long as the file to be rendered is a `.ejs` file then you shouldn't see this error, did you remove the old line in your code? `exp.engine(...)`? That may be clashing.

Comment: yeah, i did remove that line, do i need to put the .ejs in the views dir or not? @james

Comment: @SamHep0803 yep it needs to sit in the view directory path, by default this is `<applicationRoot>/views`.

Comment: well then i don't know whats wrong, because it is in there @james

Comment: @SamHep0803 I'm afraid I don't know what to tell you then, because that is the correct way to configure an EJS setup with Express. If you want you can try back the original way but for that to work you need to rename your `.ejs` files to `.html` files as you have the view engine set as `html`. If you still have problems finding files then I would recommend removing (or at least changing) your static directory location incase it's somehow conflicting, as I said in my previous edit, it's unusual to set that to the project root (unless this is an electron requirement).

Comment: @SamHep0803 does `index.js` reside in the project root folder?

Answer (score 0):

Reading [this](https://gist.github.com/joepie91/c0069ab0e0da40cc7b54b8c2203befe1) solve my problem.

Add the follwing line to your index.js file.

```
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.set("views", path.join(__dirname, "views"));
```